# Error: virtualenvwrapper.user_scripts could not run "/Users/../.virtualenvs/prod-replay/bin/preactivate": [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, zsh, oh-my-zsh, virtualenvwrapper

I am having issue with virtualenvwrapper while creating a virtual env. the error mentions that there is no such file as `"/Users/../.virtualenvs/prod-replay/bin/preactivate"`, but the preactivate file exists with the below content.

```
#!zsh
# This hook is run before this virtualenv is activated.
```

I am using zsh . how can i fix this issue?

in the ~/.zshrc file I have the below entries

```
export WORKON_HOME=~/.virtualenvs
mkdir -p $WORKON_HOME

. ~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

Comment: The path leads to a `.virtualenvs` in the root folder. I guess you environmental variable are not set up properly.

Comment: @KlausD. i have updated the question with env variables

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. Did you find a solution or workaround @ben?